# how to read file just written using yeoman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

I am using `copyTpl` to write a file, I believe its being written to an in memory file system:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath('myfile.xml'), `myfile.xml`, params);
```

Now I need to calculate a hash on this file, and write that to another file, how do I read this? Using `fs` from node does not work as this file does not yet exist on disk, also `this.fs.read()` does not seem to work either, says the file does not exist.

Comment: To format code just indent with four spaces or use the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('myfile.xml'),
      this.destinationPath('D:/public/myfile.xml'),
      params
    );
```

What this has done is basically stored your file to a destination path from which now you can pick this file for reading using the `fs` module of nodejs .